# Why does Mathematica not evaluate certain simple limits?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

*Mathematica* does not evaluate any of these limits.  It seems that the answers should be $1/x$ and $1/y$, respectively.

```
Limit[(x^k + y^k)^(-1/k), k -> ∞, Assumptions -> x > 0 && y > 0 && x > y]

Limit[(x^k + y^k)^(-1/k), k -> ∞, Assumptions -> x > 0 && y > 0 && x < y]
```

They seem to be fairly simple limits. Am I missing something here?

Comment: My guess is that `Limit` treats the expression as a complex-valued function, even though the assumptions imply otherwise.  In particular, transformations such as this are not used: `PowerExpand[Factor /@ PowerExpand[(x^k + y^k)^(-1/k) /. y -> (u x)]] /. u -> y/x`.

Comment: `Limit` often fails in cases that seem simple.  Try `Series` instead.

Comment: In this case `Series` performs no better.

Answer (score 3):

The limits evaluate for `x > 1 && y > 1` for which the larger term dominates

```
Limit[(x^k + y^k)^(-1/k), k -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> x > 1 && y > 1 && x > y]

(*  1/x  *)

Limit[(x^k + y^k)^(-1/k), k -> \[Infinity], 
 Assumptions -> x > 1 && y > 1 && x < y]

(*  1/y  *)
```